# Android: ListView filter without pressing search button

Tags: android, listview, filter, searchview

I'm creating a ListView with filter. The thing is, the filter is working, but i need to press the search button so the list can be filtered. I want to avoid that and make it auto filter when i enter a letter.

Here is the activity implementation:

```
private void setupSearchView() {

    filter = navAdapter.getFilter();

    final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    search.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    search.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    search.setIconified(true);


    int searchSrcTextId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) search.findViewById(searchSrcTextId);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        filter.filter(query);
        return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}
```

The Adapter:

```
  @Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    /**
     * A filter object which will
     * filter message key
     * */
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            list = (List<NavigationDrawerListModel>) results.values; // has the filtered values
            notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values. Only filtered values will be shown on the list
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation for publishing

            List<NavigationDrawerListModel> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<NavigationDrawerListModel>();

            if (mList == null) {
                mList = new ArrayList<NavigationDrawerListModel>(list); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
            }

            if (mListItem == null) {
                mListItem = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (NavigationDrawerListModel recipe : mList) {
                    mListItem.add(recipe.getTitle());
                }
            }

            /**
             *
             *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
             *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)
             *
             **/

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                /* CONTRACT FOR IMPLEMENTING FILTER : set the Original values to result which will be returned for publishing */
                results.count = mList.size();
                results.values = mList;
            } else {
                /* Do the filtering */
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                for (int i = 0; i < mListItem.size(); i++) {
                    String data = mListItem.get(i);
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredArrList.add(mList.get(i));
                    }
                }

                // set the Filtered result to return
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }
            return results;
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

and the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <!-- Toolbar -->

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <!-- content -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout_test"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:text="Our Content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!-- nav drawer -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <android.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/searchViewHomePage_test"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:queryHint="@string/abc_searchview_description_search"

                />


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_list_items_test"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    />

                </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.1dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/drawer_list_test"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SearchView#setOnQueryTextListener` and perform filtering in `boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)` method of `OnQueryTextListener`. So in your case move `filter.filter(query);` from `onQueryTextSubmit` to `onQueryTextChange`.

Comment: Great! That worked out. Thanks for the fast response.